# How to set an element's height relative to the screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullscreen, viewport-units

I want to set the `height` of an element as a percentage of the full-screen mode's dimensions so that when the browser window is smaller, the height does not change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

the `%` operator is dynamic it changes according to the width or height of the screen
so if you want that the length may not change you can use `px` or `pt` or even `rem` (but it depends on root elements size)

```css
height:100%;
```

#### UPDATE 2021

you can use `vh` (viewport height) this will automatically adjust to they screen height

```css
height:100vh;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could specify the `height` in [`vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length), which equates to 1% of the height of the **viewport's** (not the screen's) initial containing block.

If you actually need the `height` to be relative to the screen height, then you would have to use JavaScript's [`screen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen) object:

```
window.screen.height;
window.screen.width;
```

You can use these values directly in an `style` attribute:

```js
// 10% of the screen height:
document.getElementById('container')
  .style.height = `${ window.screen.height * 0.1 }px`;
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  
  /* Fallback value (relative to viewport, not screen) */
  height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Or create something more reusable using [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties):

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
  '--container-height', `${ window.screen.height }px`);
  
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
  '--container-width', `${ window.screen.width }px`);
```

```css
:root {
  /* We use thew viewport's dimensions as fallback values: */
  --screen-height: 100vh; 
  --screen-width: 100vw; 
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  
  /* 10% of the screen height: */
  height: calc(0.1 * var(--container-height));
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```